# Is it possible to only show your app as a receiver in the share sheet for a certain number of attachments for Android?

Tags: android, share, android-sharesheet

Hi I want my app to show in the share sheet only if the user has selected 5 or less files but I am not sure if that is possible. So far I have the following code in the manifest so that my app will show when the user selects multiple attachments. I don't want my app to deal with it when the user selects my app, I just want my app to not show up in the first place on that condition.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: No, there isn't.  You either support SEND_MULTIPLE or not.  You can choose to do something in your UI to show that you only support 5.